# Assembly syntax .space meaning

Tags: assembly

```
readings: .space  n, 0x0
```

Can anyone telll me what is the above code meaning?
From my understanding  should be reserve an address space with size `n`, then what about the `0x0`?

Comment: Which architecture and compiler is this for?

Comment: arm assembly language

Comment: Isn't this information in the assembly manual?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `0x0` is the value to fill those `n` bytes with. It's actually redundant because 0 is the default value.

Quoting from the GNU assembler manual:

> `.space size , fill`
>
> This directive emits `size` bytes, each of value `fill`. Both `size` and `fill` are absolute expressions. If the comma and `fill` are omitted, `fill` is assumed to be zero.